# How to determine whether this improper integral is convergent or not?

Tags: improper-integrals

The improper integral is

$$\int^1_0\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

It is from an old calculus exam. It should be convergent. I've looked around on how to solve it but I've had no success at all.

Edit: $0\leq\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{e^x}{x^3}$ when $0\leq x\leq 1$ and since $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^3\frac{e^x}{x^3}=1$ the improper integral is convergent. Is this right?

Comment: Use the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ (you may need to justify using it, but it’s pretty straightforward).

Comment: The integral of $1/x^3$ at $0$ is divergent, i.e., your conclusion is false.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$ we can  find $\delta>0$ so that $\Big|\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\Big|<\frac{1}{4}$ for any $x\in (0,\delta)$.

But then $$0<\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}}< \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}<\frac{3}{4\sqrt{x}}$$ on the domain $x\in (0,\delta)$.

By direct comparison $\int_0^\delta \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2\sqrt{x}}dx$ converges and hence so must your integral.

Comment: btw, where do u learn this?

Answer (score 2):

Near $x=0$, using the expansion of the exponential function you have:
$$\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2\sqrt x }\sim \frac{x^2/2}{x^2\sqrt x}=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt x} $$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can I get a reference for this method? I've never used expansions to estimate integrals

Comment: @perpersson are you familiar with Taylor expansion?

Comment: yes both taylor and maclaurin

Comment: @perpersson the method is called asymptotic test (or comparison test) and you can use it for series and integrals. Basically, you study the asymptotic behaviour of the function using its Taylor expansion

Comment: can u possibly show me same method but with more rigor? I know $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3B(x)$ where $B(x)$ is bounded near 0.  But how do I insert this expression into the integral rigorously? $\int^1_0\frac{1+x+x^2/2 +x^3B(x)-1-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}} $doesn't make sense.